# lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand -- passing function result as pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have some problem with my code.
There are the following functions:

```
static Poly PolyFromCoeff(int coeff);
static Mono MonoFromPoly(const Poly *p, int exp);
```

And in another function I have this line:

```
Mono m = MonoFromPoly(&PolyFromCoeff(10),4);
```

But I receive this error message:

> lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

If I save the first result to a variable, there is no error:

```
Poly p = PolyFromCoeff(10);
Mono m = MonoFromPoly(&p,4);
```

Why is the first solution wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As it says, operator `&` requires a lvalue as its argument, i.e. it cannot be applied to temporary values. Addresses are not associated with values, with objects only.

In the second form you instantiate an object that holds this value and you can easily take the address of that object.

Answer (score 1):

The C language expressly prohibits you from taking the address of a *rvalue* (which is what a function returns).  This clause from the [C11 standard (committee draft)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) sums it up:

> **6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1. The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
>      `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
>      not declared with the **register** storage-class specifier.

If you are confused about *lvalue* and *rvalue*, think of it like this:

- *lvalue* is something that has an identifier and storage
- *rvalue* is a temporary result or literal value

---

*If you have a C++ background, you might have been confused because the behavior of references is different.  In C++, it's okay to have this:*

```
static Poly PolyFromCoeff(int coeff);
static Mono MonoFromPoly(const Poly &p, int exp);

Mono m = MonoFromPoly( PolyFromCoeff(10), 4 );
```